# How to run the example of yesod-websockets

Tags: yesod

How do we need to run the example from [yesod-websockets?](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/tree/master/yesod-websockets) It seems it doesn't use stack, so I can't `stack build` and `stack runghc sample.hs`

Comment: and what's the proper way to convert it to use stack? I'd be happy to create a PR to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it was enough to

```
cabal install stm-lifted conduit-combinators
cabal install
runghc sample.hs
```

Next, I'll try to figure how to stackify this.